# Couchbase PascalCase JSON for property names

Tags: .net, json.net, couchbase

We are using the latest .NET client for Couchbase and have noticed that it is converting property names to camelCase rather than the original names which are in PascalCase.

This is causing us problems, as when searching using N1QL if the case of the property name is incorrect, the query does not return any results.

I did find an article on how to specify some JSON serializer settings, but this was written in 2014 and now does not work as the client has changed.

Can anyone advise how I can either change the JSON serializer to serialize in original / PascalCase or if I can specify to N1QL not to worry about case with property names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET client indeed forces everything into CamelCase by default ([source](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/blob/db07eb1be7d9a0d240f16ec5b1738950f7fbddef/Src/Couchbase/Core/Serialization/DefaultSerializer.cs#L19)).

You can customize this behavior by providing your own serializer when you initialize the `Cluster` object. You can even switch from the default Newtonsoft lib to something more efficient, like the ServiceStack serializer.

All you need to do is implement the `Couchbase.Core.Serialization.ITypeSerializer`interface and provide the factory method during `Cluster` initialization. Here is an example of [implementing a custom serializer](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-net-contrib/blob/master/Src/Couchbase.NetClient.Contrib.Serializers.Jil/JilSerializer.cs), and here is an example of [using it](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-net-contrib/blob/master/Src/Couchbase.NetClient.Contrib.Tests/Serializers/Jil/JilSerializerTests.cs#L29).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify case-insensitive searches in N1QL as follows:

```
SELECT `field1`i FROM my_bucket;
```

This will match field1, FIELD1, Field1, and any other case.

Separately, the .NET client should not be modifying your field names. If it is doing so, that is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am using the fields in a where clause which I have tried prepending an I on, but it has not worked. Full query below:

SELECT Output FROM default AS Output LEFT JOIN default AS BlockItem ON KEYS Output.BlockItemId WHERE Output.Type='Domain.ContentBlock' AND Output.Name LIKE '%24%'

Comment: Can you post the full query with all the fields quoted for case-insenstive? That is, \`BlockItemId\`i, \`Name\`i, etc.

Comment: Nothing quoted works. tried something very simple of SELECT 'name'i FROM default and I got a result list of just name no actual data

Comment: You need to use back ticks for your quoting: SELECT default.\`name\`i

Comment: that has managed to work. Unfortunately the structure required to do this is just as much work, if not more than allowing for oddly capitalised property names. You mentioned that it the serializer should not be changing property names... where should I turn to get that fixed?

Comment: You should be able to file a bug here https://issues.couchbase.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to implement your own version of `Couchbase.Core.Serialization.ITypeSerializer` to change from camelCase to PascalCase. If you're fine with using the default serializer (Newtonsoft.JSON), you can just so this in the `ClientConfiguration`:

```
return new ClientConfiguration
        {
            Servers = _servers.ToList(),
            BucketConfigs = new Dictionary<string, BucketConfiguration>
            {
                { "default", new BucketConfiguration
                {
                    Password = _password,
                    UseSsl = false
                }}
            },
            UseSsl = false,
            Serializer = () => new DefaultSerializer(
                new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
                },
                new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
                }),
        };
```

It's pretty ironic that the default contract resolver is PascalCase but if you don't explicitly tell it to use the default contract resolver it will use the camelCase one as a default :)